# Any ideas for a Spark scalable collect()

Tags: apache-spark

Collect() action is quite useful. You get your data without having to write a file. But it is not scalable in the sense that collecting too much data may cause an Out Of Memory exception. By the way, toLocalIterator() action is quite scalable, but it collects the data one partition by one which is not very efficient. Any idea for a scalable collect()? Something like a configurable iterator?

Comment: RDD foreach probably will be ok for you - it will iterate over all entries in RDD

Answer (score 0):

Collect method force all worker to return the relevant data to master.
As Collect method returns Array so master needs to create the whole array locally in the memory because it is designed this way.
This is a restriction for developer that data that collect method returns should be less then the size of avalaible memory of master else it will give you the outofmemory exception

You can try foreach that might help.